# Inserir N comentários, tendo a opção de editá-los a qualquer momento e depois salvar esses comenários

Tags: c#, json

Estou fazendo a parte de cadastro de um sistema, nesse cadastro é possível salvar vários comentários e editá-los a medida que vamos inserindo-os ou posteriormente, porém deve funcionar da seguinte forma, o usuário insere os dados, na mesma tela, ele clica em Incluir comentários, (reforçando com outras palavras) ao incluir esses comentários, não deve ser armazenado diretamente no banco, pois o mesmo deve ficar salvo em algum tipo de cache até que o usuário cadastrante termine de inserir todos os outros comentários (sempre clicando em Incluir comentários) e os outros dados e clicando em salvar.

Desde já, grato.

Comment: E qual é o problema/dúvida?

Comment: Adicione o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode gravar tudo em session, determinando um tempo de expiração e um ID para ela. No final, você lê a session, grava, e limpa a session. Ou trabalhar com cookies, que utilza processamento do usuário, não do server, seguindo da mesma forma.

Geralmente utilizamos "cookies", para não sobrecarregar o servidor caso o site tenha muitos acessos.

Comment: Fiz através de Session, muito obrigado André!